# if else where cell is contained within the column name string

Tags: r

Been having a difficult time trying to code this problem out.  So effectively I am trying to select the cell in a wide data frame where the values in one column are contained with the column name's string.  I generally use the tidyverse in my workflows and cannot get anything in that verse to work.  Tried applying, for looping through the rows.  Got some things to work but they are VERY slow.  The attached data frame snippet is just the first 10 rows of a 1.8 million row data frame. So using `tidy::gather` is out of the question here.  Any thoughts on how I could go about accomplishing this would be of great use because it comes up a lot more often than I would have expected.

[Data can be found here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i1ozPb-CgmHbmV10ajEERLX4QsppT9ni/view?usp=sharing)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(foreach)

df <- read_csv('test_data.csv')
```

[image]

So here I am trying to find the variable for `fire_year` that is contained within the wide `var_` fields. So for instance, here if `fire_year` = 1998 then I would want to capture the value in the column named `var_1998`. This is the closest I have got to getting a solution (and it works!) but it takes forever on the full data frame:

```
df_slim <- foreach(df=iter(df, by='row'), .combine=rbind, 
                  .packages = c('dplyr', "tidyverse")) %do% {
                    df_out <- df %>%
                      gather(key = key, value = out_var, -fpa_id, -fire_year) %>%
                      separate(key,
                               into = c("tmp1", 'zyear'),
                               sep = "_") %>%
                      mutate(var = ifelse(fire_year == zyear, out_var, NA)) %>%
                      na.omit() %>%
                      dplyr::select(fpa_id, fire_year, var)
                    return(df_out)
                  }
```

[image]

I cannot figure fast, efficient way to accomplish for the life of me! At this point I have calculated that it will take 160 hours to complete this for loop on the 1.7 million row data frame! If someone could point me in the right direction I would be eternally grateful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you need, but here is my take on it (using data.table)

```
library(data.table)

    dt <- data.table(test_data)

    setkey(dt, "fire_year")
    for(i in unique(dt[["fire_year"]])){
      dt[fire_year == i, var:= get(paste("var", i, sep = "_"))]
    }
```

And then subset the cols you need

```
dt_slim <- dt[,.SD, .SDcols = c("fpa_id", "fire_year", "var")]
dt_slim

        fpa_id fire_year var
 1: FS-1418827      2004   0
 2: FS-1418835      2004   9
 3: FS-1418845      2004   0
 4: FS-1418847      2004   0
 5: FS-1418849      2004   0
 6: FS-1418851      2004   0
 7: FS-1418859      2004   0
 8: FS-1418826      2005   0
 9: FS-1418854      2005   0
10: FS-1418856      2005 114
```

Not tested on your 1.8 million rows. Should be relativly fast. Interested on the timings though...

Comment: Wow that is perfect.  I haven't used data.table much and this is inspiring me to drive into that package more.  The method I illustrated above took 160 hours, this seconds over the 1.8 million records! Very impressive!  Thanks for your help

Comment: Happy to help! I would be interested in a neat base and dplyr solution and how they scale.